# Rename Excel worksheet using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

How do i rename excel worksheet using xlsxwriter in python. I am using python 2.7 in linux to create excel reports. But cannot find an option to rename the tabs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the name of a worksheet while adding it via [`add_worksheet()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-add-worksheet):

```
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('My Custom Name')
```

Note that [you cannot set the name of an existing worksheet](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-get-name):

> There is no `set_name()` method. The only safe way to set the worksheet name is via the `add_worksheet()` method.

Comment: Thanks !! Perfect. I did search in doc. but could not find this example in the worksheet class.

Answer (score -1):

Here, Simple Solution,

```
        book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
        sheet1 = book.add_worksheet("Match")
        sheet2 = book.add_worksheet("Not_Match")
```

Answer (score -4):

Another way without using any modules:

```
 with open('example.xls', 'r') as f1, open('renamed.xls', 'w') as f2:
     f2.write(f1.read())
```