# Rename tab in an excel sheet - xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test_file.xlsx')
tab_1 = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('tab1')
```

Using the above code I have successfully loaded my workbook. 
The sheet, **test_file.xlsx** has three tabs inside it. *tab1*, *tab2* and *tab3*.

Is there a way I can rename tab1 to something else **without using openpyxl**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Excel worksheet using xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421631/rename-excel-worksheet-using-xlsxwriter)

Comment: Yeah, I read that. But the guy said that existing sheets cannot be renamed.

Comment: I want to maintain the contents of tab1 since its a tab that has pre-populated data which I don't want to lose.